# Dask failing with/due to Tornado error 'too many files open'

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I am running Jupyter notebook launched from Anaconda.  When trying to initialize a distributed Dask environment the following Tornado package error is thrown:

```
tornado.application - ERROR - Multiple exceptions in yield list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 883, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 208, in _start_worker
    yield w._start()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 157, in _start
    response = yield self.instantiate()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 226, in instantiate
    self.process.start()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 351, in start
    self.init_result_q = init_q = mp_context.Queue()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 102, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 41, in __init__
    self._reader, self._writer = connection.Pipe(duplex=False)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 517, in Pipe
    fd1, fd2 = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
tornado.application - ERROR - Multiple exceptions in yield list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 883, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 208, in _start_worker
    yield w._start()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 143, in _start
    listen_args=self.listen_args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 272, in listen
    self.listener.start()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 396, in start
    backlog=backlog)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 134, in bind_sockets
    sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 151, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in __init__(self, address, loop, timeout, set_as_default, scheduler_file, security, asynchronous, name, heartbeat_interval, serializers, deserializers, extensions, direct_to_workers, **kwargs)
    634             ext(self)
    635 
--> 636         self.start(timeout=timeout)
    637 
    638         from distributed.recreate_exceptions import ReplayExceptionClient

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in start(self, **kwargs)
    757             self._started = self._start(**kwargs)
    758         else:
--> 759             sync(self.loop, self._start, **kwargs)
    760 
    761     def __await__(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in sync(loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
    275             e.wait(10)
    276     if error[0]:
--> 277         six.reraise(*error[0])
    278     else:
    279         return result[0]

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in f()
    260             if timeout is not None:
    261                 future = gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=timeout), future)
--> 262             result[0] = yield future
    263         except Exception as exc:
    264             error[0] = sys.exc_info()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1131 
   1132                     try:
-> 1133                         value = future.result()
   1134                     except Exception:
   1135                         self.had_exception = True

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1139                     if exc_info is not None:
   1140                         try:
-> 1141                             yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
   1142                         finally:
   1143                             # Break up a reference to itself

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in _start(self, timeout, **kwargs)
    820                 self.cluster = LocalCluster(loop=self.loop, asynchronous=True,
    821                                             **self._startup_kwargs)
--> 822                 yield self.cluster
    823             except (OSError, socket.error) as e:
    824                 if e.errno != errno.EADDRINUSE:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1131 
   1132                     try:
-> 1133                         value = future.result()
   1134                     except Exception:
   1135                         self.had_exception = True

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py in _wrap_awaitable(awaitable)
    601     that will later be wrapped in a Task by ensure_future().
    602     """
--> 603     return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
    604 
    605 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1139                     if exc_info is not None:
   1140                         try:
-> 1141                             yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
   1142                         finally:
   1143                             # Break up a reference to itself

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py in _start(self, ip, n_workers)
    189         self.scheduler.start(scheduler_address)
    190 
--> 191         yield [self._start_worker(**self.worker_kwargs) for i in range(n_workers)]
    192 
    193         self.status = 'running'

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1131 
   1132                     try:
-> 1133                         value = future.result()
   1134                     except Exception:
   1135                         self.had_exception = True

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in callback(f)
    881             for f in children:
    882                 try:
--> 883                     result_list.append(f.result())
    884                 except Exception as e:
    885                     if future.done():

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1139                     if exc_info is not None:
   1140                         try:
-> 1141                             yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
   1142                         finally:
   1143                             # Break up a reference to itself

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py in _start_worker(self, death_timeout, **kwargs)
    206               death_timeout=death_timeout,
    207               silence_logs=self.silence_logs, **kwargs)
--> 208         yield w._start()
    209 
    210         self.workers.append(w)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1131 
   1132                     try:
-> 1133                         value = future.result()
   1134                     except Exception:
   1135                         self.had_exception = True

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1139                     if exc_info is not None:
   1140                         try:
-> 1141                             yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
   1142                         finally:
   1143                             # Break up a reference to itself

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py in _start(self, addr_or_port)
    155 
    156         logger.info('        Start Nanny at: %r', self.address)
--> 157         response = yield self.instantiate()
    158         if response == 'running':
    159             assert self.worker_address

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1131 
   1132                     try:
-> 1133                         value = future.result()
   1134                     except Exception:
   1135                         self.had_exception = True

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1139                     if exc_info is not None:
   1140                         try:
-> 1141                             yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
   1142                         finally:
   1143                             # Break up a reference to itself

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py in instantiate(self, comm)
    224                 result = yield gen.with_timeout(
    225                         timedelta(seconds=self.death_timeout),
--> 226                         self.process.start()
    227                 )
    228             except gen.TimeoutError:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1131 
   1132                     try:
-> 1133                         value = future.result()
   1134                     except Exception:
   1135                         self.had_exception = True

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    324                 try:
    325                     orig_stack_contexts = stack_context._state.contexts
--> 326                     yielded = next(result)
    327                     if stack_context._state.contexts is not orig_stack_contexts:
    328                         yielded = _create_future()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py in start(self)
    350 
    351         self.init_result_q = init_q = mp_context.Queue()
--> 352         self.child_stop_q = mp_context.Queue()
    353         uid = uuid.uuid4().hex
    354 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py in Queue(self, maxsize)
    100         '''Returns a queue object'''
    101         from .queues import Queue
--> 102         return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
    103 
    104     def JoinableQueue(self, maxsize=0):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py in __init__(self, maxsize, ctx)
     39             from .synchronize import SEM_VALUE_MAX as maxsize
     40         self._maxsize = maxsize
---> 41         self._reader, self._writer = connection.Pipe(duplex=False)
     42         self._rlock = ctx.Lock()
     43         self._opid = os.getpid()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py in Pipe(duplex)
    515             c2 = Connection(s2.detach())
    516         else:
--> 517             fd1, fd2 = os.pipe()
    518             c1 = Connection(fd1, writable=False)
    519             c2 = Connection(fd2, readable=False)

OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

The problem seems to be with 'Tornado' as alluded to [here][https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1941].  My version of Anaconda has Tornado 5.1.1 with Python 3.7.3 and Dask 1.25.1

This is the code that is being run:

```
%%time
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.distributed as dist

client = dist.Client()
```

Several weeks ago I was able to run some small distributed Dask examples and I can run Dask successfully without invoking a Client.  If the problem is Tornado is there a workaround?

In case anyone was wondering about MacOS process file limits -
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround.  On MacOS it looks like using command line to change file limits is only good for launches from the terminal.  Furthermore if you restart, the limits are reset to original values (256 was default on my machine).  To set the limits properly you have to create a file 'limit.maxfiles.plist' in /etc/Library/LaunchDaemons and restart.  I got this from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1).  This works around the 'too many files' error but likely only postpones the problem with Tornado.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Edited to fix the broken link

Answer (score 3):

I found the same issue with the master branch yesterday (5/20/2019) and found this: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/733. For me, I simply looked at the underlying script for dask_scheduler and replicated it in Pycharm:

```
    from distributed.cli.dask_scheduler import go
       if __name__ == '__main__':
         go()
```

Starts up, is stable and I've attached a worker to it from the command line.